# Getting string with regex from a website

Tags: php, regex

Hi i want to grab ip and port on https://www.socks-proxy.net/. I can grab ip with regex pattern

`'/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/'`

but how to grab port ? i only can grab ip without port. How i can grab ip and port?

Comment: You are probably better of parsing the HTML doc and searching the tags for the content you want to have.

Comment: i can find with explode but i want to learn regex pattern

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look an the source code of the website. You can see, that everything is separated by TD-Tags.

So you would have to expand your regex to get the next column like this:
`(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})<\/td><td>(\d{1,5})`

See results here: https://regex101.com/r/V7sh0d/1

Comment: i saw timeout on https://regex101.com/r/V7sh0d/1

Comment: It's working an my machine. Just try the regex in your project. It should work there as well.

Comment: thanks sir you save my time, i use preg_match_all('/<\/td><td>(\d{1,5})/', $str, $match);

Comment: This could also match for the column `last checked` (because `\d{1,5}` will match for '33 seconds ago'. I would recommend to use my version. You can just group the 2nd part, but you should use the whole statement. Please accept my answer as a solution when you are happy with the outcome